# Connecting to Cloud SQL using Compute Engine via JDBC

Tags: android, android-studio, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-proxy

I cannot connect to my database thru Compute Engine.

Things I have done so far:

1. Setup my Compute Engine
2. Connect my Compute Engine to my Cloud SQL
3. Install and run Cloud Proxy on my Compute Engine
4. Included the JDBC Jar file on my libs folder
5. Created the JDBC Connection string

> "jdbc:mysql:///?cloudSqlInstance=&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.mysql.SocketFactory;user=&password=";

6. Added dependency on my Gradle file

> -implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
> -implementation 'com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8:1.1.0'

Here is the stack trace:

> W/System.err: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot
> connect to MySQL server on localhost:3,306. W/System.err: Make sure
> that there is a MySQL server running on the machine/port you are
> trying to connect to and that the machine this software is running on
> is able to connect to this host/port (i.e. not firewalled). Also make
> sure that the server has not been started with the --skip-networking
> flag.
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:110)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:470)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:569)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:237)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.dedase.dedaseconstruction.ui.login.LoginActivity$GetPatientID.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:150)
> at com.dedase.dedaseconstruction.ui.login.LoginActivity$GetPatientID.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:136)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
> W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.mysql.cj.protocol.SocketConnection
> com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.getSocketConnection()' on a
> null object reference
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:980)
> at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
> W/System.err:     at
> com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
> ... 12 more I/Choreographer: Skipped 58 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. I/zygote: Do full code
> cache collection, code=123KB, data=111KB
> After code cache collection, code=117KB, data=78KB

Comment: You can follow this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) which also includes a tutotial on, how to connect MYSQL client from Compute Engine. I would suggest you, try to connect the MYSQL client without JDBC, so that you can isolate the issue.
[Here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory) is another tutorial of Cloud SQL Connector for Java.

Answer (score 0):

This line `localhost:3,306.` looks really suspicious. Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere?
You probably came across this [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-jdbc-socket-factory), and it's not very accurate. I don't have a java client at hand to test it, but I do use Cloud SQL with a different stack and the point of using Proxy is that your app connects to the DB via it as if the DB itself is running locally. Your connection string should not have anything apart from creds and `localhost:3306`.